# Output not displayed in Streamlit, when making a LLM chatbot with Gemini-Pro

Tags: python, bots, chatbot, streamlit, large-language-model

I'm trying to build an LLM chatbot with Gemini-Pro on Google Colab and I added a web interface using Streamlit. The problem is that input is successfully submitted but the output from Gemini isn't getting displayed on the web interface.

Here's the code:

```
!pip install -q streamlit
!streamlit hello 
!pip install python-dotenv
!pip install google-generativeai
```

```
%%writefile app.py

import os
import streamlit as st
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import google.generativeai as gen_ai
load_dotenv()

st.set_page_config(
    page_title="Chat with Gemini Pro",
    page_icon=":brain:",
    layout="centered"
)

GOOGLE_API_KEY = os.getenv("GOOGLE_API_KEY")
gen_ai.configure(api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY)
model = gen_ai.GenerativeModel("gemini-pro")

def translate_role_for_streamlit(user_role):
  if user_role == "model":
    return "assistant"
  else:
    return user_role

if not(hasattr(st.session_state, "chat_session")):
  st.session_state.chat_session = model.start_chat(history=[])
st.title("Chat Bot")

for message in st.session_state.chat_session.history:
  with st.chat_message(translate_role_for_streamlit(message.role)):
    st.markdown(message.parts[0].text)

user_prompt = st.chat_input("Ask Chat bot...")
if user_prompt:
  st.chat_message("user").markdown(user_prompt)
  gemini_response = st.session_state.chat_session.send_message(user_prompt)
  with st.chat_message("assistant"):
    st.markdown(gemini_response.text)
```

```
!npm install localtunnel 
!streamlit run app.py &>/content/logs.txt & 
!npx localtunnel --port 8501
```

Here is the web interface:

[eimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxWNB.png)

I tried changing the API key and tried modifying the `getenv("GOOGLE_API_KEY")` but both didn't work...